# merge / append files and re-number first column in unix

Tags: file, unix, sed, awk

I am many (3 just an example) text files in different directories (3 different names) like following:

Directory: A, file name: run.txt  format: txt tab deliminated

```
; file one 
10     0.2   0.5   0.3
20     0.1   0.6   0.8
30     0.2   0.1   0.1
40     0.1   0.5   0.3
```

Directory: B, file name: run.txt  format: txt tab deliminated

```
; file two 
10     0.2   0.1   0.2
30     0.1   0.6   0.8
50     0.2   0.1   0.1
70     0.3   0.4   0.4
```

Directory: C, file name: run.txt  format: txt tab deliminated

```
; file three 
10     0.3   0.3   0.3
20     0.3   0.6   0.8
30     0.1   0.1   0.1
40     0.2   0.2   0.3
```

I want to combine all three run.txt files into single and renumber the first column. The resulting new file will look like:

```
; file combined 
10     0.2   0.5   0.3
20     0.1   0.6   0.8
30     0.2   0.1   0.1
40     0.1   0.5   0.3

50     0.2   0.1   0.2
70     0.1   0.6   0.8
90     0.2   0.1   0.1
110    0.3   0.4   0.4

120    0.3   0.3   0.3
130    0.3   0.6   0.8
140    0.1   0.1   0.1
150    0.2   0.2   0.3
```

This what my codes are at:

```
cat A/run.txt B/run.txt C/run.txt > combined.txt
```

(1) I do not know how to take care of renumbering by first column

(2) Also I do not how to take care of comment starting with ";"

**Edit:**

Let me be clear about the number scheme:
A/run.txt, B/run.txt and C/run.txt are actually parallel run to combined into one. 
so each will have stored samples with run number. However gap can be uneven among the run.

(1) for first file A/run.txt (gap is 10, 20-10, 30-20)

```
10, 10+10, 20+10, 30+10
```

(2) for second file B/run.txt, starts from 10 but has gap of 20 
(eg. 30-10, 50-70, 70-50)

```
40 (from last line of the first file) + 10 (first in file two) = 50, 
 50 + 20 = 70,70 + 20 = 90,  90+ 20 = 110
```

(3) file C/run.txt starts from 10 and increment is 10

```
110 (last number in file 2) + 10 = 120, 120+ 10 = 130,
 130+10 = 140, 140+10 = 150`
```

Comment: The numbering scheme is not clear. Why a number 80 or a number 100 do not exist?

Comment: thanks, it was my fault ..the numbers between the dataset adds up, however in interval may be different- error is corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    printf "%s\n", "; file combined"
}
! /^;/ {
    if (FILENAME != prevfile) {
        prevnum = $1
        prevfile = FILENAME
        interval = 10
        c = 0
    }
    c++
    if (c == 2) {
        interval = $1 - prevnum
    }
    $1 = (i += interval)
    print
}
```

To run it:

```
$ ./renumber {A,B,C}/run.txt
```

Given your sample input, it produces output that exactly matches your sample.

Comment: very nice works, would it be possible to take the gaps out between the files in combined file, I just them for the clarity purpose

Comment: Just little thing, I tried to apply all directories (potentially I will have x number of them with ./renumber.txt {*}/run.txt, but do not work....do you have any suggestion on that ..

Comment: @hijo: remove the curly braces from around the asterisk. You only use them for a constructed list (for example). So it would be `./renumber.txt */run.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk`:

```
  awk 'BEGIN{l=0;print "; file combined"}; {if($1!=";")print l,$2,$3,$4;l=l+10}'  A/run.txt B/run.txt C/run.txt > combined.txt
```

**EDIT**

I made a guess about your numbering scheme (you've provided still no spec) and come up with:

```
  awk 'BEGIN{line=0;last=0;print "; file combined"}; !/^;/{if($1<last){line=last+$1}else{line=line+$1-last;last=$1};print line,$2,$3,$4}' \
  A/run.txt B/run.txt C/run.txt > combined.txt
```

Is it what you mean?

Comment: thanks for the reply...I am getting different value for the second file as this as different interval 20 not 10...otherwise perfect

Comment: Again, explain the numbering scheme you want. The code above simply increments by 10.

Comment: Sorry my bad again, although I have the above smaller datasets correct but combined wrong. I corrected

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1="";print NR"0",$0}' A/run.txt B/run.txt C/run.txt > combined.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk -F'[\t]' 'lastfile!=FILENAME{lastfile=FILENAME;i=l};{$1+=i;l=$1};1' A/run.txt B/run.txt C/run.txt > combined.txt
```